# Display multiple rating star jquery bar rating in laravel 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, laravel-5

I want to display multiple star rating. I am having problem getting the correct rating value in jQuery loop.

My html looks like this :

```
<select id="example{{$review->id}}" class="example" review-id="{{$review->id}}" data-rating="{{$review->rating}}">
           <option value=""></option>
           <option value="1">1</option>
           <option value="2">2</option>
           <option value="3">3</option>
           <option value="4">4</option>
           <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

My jQuery:

```
  $(function() {
    $('.example').each(function(){
    var x = $('select').attr('data-rating');
    console.log(x);
    var review_id = $('select').attr('review-id');
    console.log(review_id);
  $('#example' +review_id).barrating({
    theme: 'fontawesome-stars',
    showSelectedRating: true,
    initialRating: x,
    readonly: true
  });
  });
});
```

Example data :

> 1st result is 5 star rating and review_id = 1
>
> 2nd result is 4 star rating and review_id = 2

In jQuery, it loops correctly 2 times but both result of x and review_id are 5 star rating and id of 1.

How to solve this so jquery-bar-rating star can display correctly on both results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating your script to the below.

```
$(function() {
    $('.example').each(function() {
        var x = $(this).attr('data-rating');
        console.log(x);
        var review_id = $(this).attr('review-id');
        console.log(review_id);
        $('#example' +review_id).barrating({
            theme: 'fontawesome-stars',
            showSelectedRating: true,
            initialRating: x,
            readonly: true
        });
    });
});
```

In your jQuery .each() loop, you should reference $(this) to retrieve the data for the active element in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix is targeting class instead of ID.

Example:

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
      $('.example').barrating({
        theme: 'fontawesome-stars',
        initialRating: $('.example').data('current-rating'),
      });
   });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<select class="example">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<select class="example">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```